# Server push jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have jqgrid displaying some data which is coming from a remote service. Initially we show static data but on click of refresh button we have to load fresh data. 
The remote service is an async operation.

Now my question is how to update the grid when I receive the response.

How can I push the data back to client browser. I don't want to use polling mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you a way to register server notification about changing the data ([WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [Web Notification](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/)s, [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr), [Push API](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/)) you need just call `reloadGrid` inside of the corresponding notification event handler. If the notification contains changed rows you can use `setRowData` to modify the changed row only (or `setCell` to change specified cell only) without reloading of the whole grid.